# how to solve apollonius problem( $CCC$ case) with compass and straight edge

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

Given three circles, how to construct another circle that is tangent to the three circles with compass and straight edge?

Well, this problem can be reduced to ($\rm\color{purple
} {PCC} $ case) by shrinking the smallest circle into a point. But I also don't know how to solve ($PCC$ case). The problem has $8$ solutions in general. Any hint? [image]

Comment: I doubt you get an answer, because it needs a lot of images. Just "google" for 'apollonius CCC', youtube has some good videos.

Comment: Here you'll find everything: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Apollonius.shtml

Comment: wow that is so nice. thank you